# Can you define your own template variables in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

In Eclipse there are templates that help you by automatically inserting some code or comments. You can edit these templates yourself via Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates. There are so-called "template variables" that you can use to make these templates a little smarter.

For instance, there is the ${see_to_overridden} variable that inserts "@see my.package.name.SpuerclassName#methodName(int, my.other.package.SomeType, ...)" into a javadoc comment. It would be really great if I could define my own variables, so that I could obtain Superclassname, SomeType etc. without having the "@see" thing prepended to it so that I could for instance link to the appropriate method. There appear to exist no template variables for this, so I was wondering if there was any way to create your own template variables.

Comment: This is such a good question. I've often wanted to do this but never figured out if it's even possible. For the first time I just started to wish there was a way to subscribe to a question and get an e-mail message when answers arrive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [Blog post](http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/jdtui/2007/12/04/text-templates-2/) ([alternative link](http://web.archive.org/web/20100414054049/http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/jdtui/2007/12/04/text-templates-2/)) by the eclipse team, you can.

Extend org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates, add a org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.TemplateVariableResolver and fill in the values required by the system. They should be self explanatory if you ever defined your own template.

Then implement the resolver, replacing your variable with a appropriate string.

The Blog post holds more details and screenshots.

Comment: Hey there, just found this post via Google, and unfortunately the blog post link you gave is broken. I don't suppose you know where to find a similar blog post? PlanetEclipse.org does not appear to have a search function (or any other way to navigate by date o search term), and my Google-Fu has failed me..

Comment: No, sorry. Can't find it any longer.

Comment: The corresponding extension point is well documented [org.eclipse.ui.editors.templates](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_editors_templates.html)