# eclipse template variable manipulation

Tags: eclipse-templates

Is there any way to manipulate the value of variables in Eclipse templates?

For example, in the following template code:

```
public class ${file} extends Activity
{
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_${enclosing_project});
    }
}
//Change the leading letter of ${enclosing_project} to lower case and remove the .java from ${file}
```

I would like the file name inserted to be myFile and not myFile.java and I would like the project name inserted to be myProject and not MyProject.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/431636/329589

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you define your own template variables in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431465/can-you-define-your-own-template-variables-in-eclipse)